# How can I get the width of built-in browser sidebars at left and right?

Tags: javascript, browser

I want to be able to identify the location of a specific UX element --- e.g. a specific `<div>` or `<section>` --- in a video of a browser screen, captured with the browser [`MediaDevices` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices). I am streaming the video along with a data stream which can contain values from the browser window being streamed (e.g. `window.outerWidth`, element bounding boxes, etc.).

If someone shares a *tab* in Chrome or Edge, it's easy --- I can locate the element with its `getClientBoundingRect()` and I know the shared video is just the viewport, so the x and y values will be true.

If someone shares a *window*, there are UX elements at the top (tabs, address bar, etc.) and potentially at the left and right (Safari sidebar, Edge Bingbar). I can use `window.innerWidth` and `window.outerWidth` to determine the total width of the UX elements to the side, but I don't know if the difference is caused by elements on the left or the right.

Is there any JS API in the browser that can tell me the *offsets* from browser sidebars on the left and right?